# Is there a LIKE Clause for querying XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and am wondering if there is any way to do a LIKE clause in my xml searches.

Here's a sample query:

```
            SELECT  Id, CaseNumber, XmlTest
            FROM UploadReport 
            WHERE 
            CASE 
                  WHEN @lastName != '' AND XmlTest.exist('(/CodeFiveReport/Parties/Party/Name/LastName[text()=sql:variable("@lastName")])') = 1 THEN 1
                  WHEN @firstName != '' AND XmlTest.exist('(/CodeFiveReport/Parties/Party/Name/FirstName[text()=sql:variable("@firstName")])') = 1 THEN 1
                  WHEN @middleName != '' AND XmlTest.exist('(/CodeFiveReport/Parties/Party/Name/MiddleName[text()=sql:variable("@middleName")])') = 1 THEN 1
                  WHEN @ssn != '' AND XmlTest.exist('(/CodeFiveReport/Parties/Party/SocialSecurityNumber[text()=sql:variable("@ssn")])') = 1 THEN 1             
                  ELSE 0
            END = 1
```

I would like to do `WHERE LastName like @lastName + '%'` basically.

EDIT:

Working query:

```
    SELECT  Id, CaseNumber, XmlTest
            FROM UploadReport 
            WHERE 
                 XmlTest.exist('(/CodeFiveReport/Parties/Party/Name/LastName[contains(text()[1], "Sm")])') = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `contains()`?

```
[contains(sql:variable("@lastName"))]
```